# The fields of Model in Extjs4 can not contains some special characters, such as dot, dash

Tags: extjs, model, character, field

I have to maintain a legacy project which developed by extjs4.2. But i found the grid cannot use a  store with dynamic fields. And the field contains character dash and minus that cause errors. Please just take a look the following code snippet and focus on the fields of the grid store.  It will throw syntax error 'Invalid left-hand in assignment'.

```
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
       title:'mygrid',
       store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store'{
         fields:['group','alfa=-2.0','alfa=0','alf=2.0'],
         data:[
            {'group':'beta', 'alfa=-2.0':1.3, 'alfa=0':1.4, 'alfa=2.0':1.5 },
            {'group':'beta', 'alfa=-2.0':1.3, 'alfa=0':1.4, 'alfa=2.0':1.5 },
         ]
       }),
    
     columns:[
        {'dataIndex':'group','header':'group'},
        {'dataIndex':'alfa=-2.0','header':'alfa=-2.0'},
        {'dataIndex':'alfa=0','header':'alfa=0'},
        {'dataIndex':'alfa=2.0','header':'alfa=2.0'}
     ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample contains a syntax error. `Ext.create('Ext.data.Store'{` there is a `,` missing after the first argument.

In the background Ext is calling `recordDataExtractorTemplate` what will try to access the record values with the dot notation. This results a code `value = source.alfa=-2 && source.alfa=-2.0;` what is obviously syntactically incorrect.

Any of the solutions below may work. It is up to you which one you go for.

- The quickest solution to change the field names in your code if possible if those fields are not used widely in the app.
- You can check if later versions of Ext fixes this problem. However the migration can be a pain.
- You can create an override of `Ext.data.reader.Reader` and patch the failing function.

Comment: Thanks, I'v changed the name of the field, It's the easiest way i think.

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way to go if not a huge refactor involved. If you are happy with the details I have provided then can you accept the answer please?